# Merging multiple dataframes in loop based on same suffix in variable names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge dataframes from demand_dataframe_list with supply_dataframe_list when the suffix is identical.

```py
demand_dataframe_list = [data_Market1, data_Market2] 
supply_dataframe_list = [df_supply2_Market1, df_supply2_Market2]
```

For example, `data_Market1` should be merged with `df_supply2_Market1` and `data_Market2` should be merged with `df_supply2_Market2`.

Here Market1 and Market2 suffix should be used to get the merged data based on common columns present in each dataframes which is 'Col1' and 'Col2'.

Below is my try
I am getting the empty dataframe using the code help. Appreciate your help !

```py
merged_dataframes = []

for demand_df, supply_df in zip(demand_dataframe_list, supply_dataframe_list):
    print(demand_df)
    demand_suffix = demand_df.name.split('_')[-1]  # Extract the suffix from the demand dataframe name
    supply_suffix = supply_df.name.split('_')[-1]  # Extract the suffix from the supply dataframe name
    merged_df = pd.merge(demand_df, supply_df, how="inner", on=['Col1', 'Col2'])
    merged_dataframes.append(merged_df)
```

Comment: Consider keeping data frames in long format where you can then just merge by *market* and *number*. Suffixed numbered columns may not be an optimal data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `name` attribute has previously been set on the different dataframes, getting it will raise an exception.

The following helper function provides a more robust way to get the suffix of the variable names:

```py
def get_suffix(df):
    return [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0].split("_")[-1]
```

Then, you can do a more extensive comparison of both lists by replacing `zip` with [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from Python standard library's `itertools` module and make your code more readable with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
merged_dataframes = [
    pd.merge(demand_df, supply_df, how="inner", on=["Col1", "Col2"])
    for demand_df, supply_df in product(demand_dataframe_list, supply_dataframe_list)
    if get_suffix(demand_df) == get_suffix(supply_df)
]
```